# Jquery reload DIV every x seconds not working in FireFox or IE

Tags: jquery

I am new to Jquery I have some code that reloads a DIV every x seconds which works fine in Safari on iPhones and iPads but doesn't seem to work in FireFox or IE, I think it's a cache problem.  Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong or how to avoid cache in FF and IE.

```
<script>
$(function() 
{
startRefresh();
});
function startRefresh() 
{ 
setTimeout(startRefresh,1000);
$.get('index.htm', function(data) 
{
    $('#container').html(data);  
 });
}
</script>
```

Comment: you are making an ajax call to 'index.htm' every second. Since ajax is async, you cannot expect the result to come back every second and update the content.

Comment: Just curious but why would you reload something every second? This is not a good idea and I'm sure there is a better solution to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi DinoMyte,
I am loading the DIV that conatins an image within index.htm, it seems to work fine in Safari on Apple devices.

Comment: Hi jnoreiga,
An image on the server something.jpg changes every x seconds but the file name remains the same.  It can change every 1-15 seconds so I want to update the page as soon as it has changed.

Comment: have you considered signalr? That way the image will only update when there is a changed. It pretty much works as a server sending messages and 1 to many clients listening for these messages. Once the client receives the message an action can be completed. Check it out

Comment: Thanks jnoreiga,
In this case I can't use ASP or ASP.net.

Comment: You could use it in conjunction. You can possibly DDOS yourself on an interval. Many users hitting your server on an interval like that.

Answer (score 2):

This problem maybe is cache, try this.

```
function startRefresh() 
{ 
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); //Try disable cache!!!
   var rnd = Math.random();
   $.get('index.htm?v='+rnd, function(data) 
   {
      $('#container').html(data);  
   });
}
var interval;
$(document).ready(function(){
  interval = setInterval(startRefresh,1000);
});
```

Generate a random number and send with parameter, brownser force get new version of page.

SetTimeout runs one time and setInterval run aways and you be clear with `clearInterval(myInterval)`

see more about [ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/).

try and let me know.

Comment: I'd just recommend putting the `setTimeOut` in the callback, so this doesn't stack multiple calls.

Comment: 1000 is 1second, this test maybe generate error, try with 5000 in you dev machine, to best test

Comment: Thanks RBoschini,
Great idea but it still seems to cache in FireFox and IE still not reloading the DIV, I've also tried at 5000 (5 seconds)

Comment: @MattCode i modify the code, try $.ajaxSetup({cache:false}) before ajaxrequest.

Comment: Thanks RBoschini but it's still not working in IE and FirefFox, fine in Safari on ios.

Comment: IE sucks :(, need change cache configuration, but client not know this, is a problem.